# How to install vendor folder

Tags: composer-php

I cloned project from [https://github.com/victorfleite/blog-php-oop <sup>archived</sup>](https://web.archive.org/web/20180627085126/https://github.com/victorfleite/blog-php-oop) .

But how to create `vendor` folder and install any dependency?

Comment: You should probably run `composer install` command in project directory. If you don't know what Composer is, reading the docs would be a good start: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Comment: Use `composer -vvvv install` to see if there are some problem in the process.

Comment: Hello, I cannot run "composer install" even after I have completed all the steps mentioned here https://getcomposer.org/download/. I could see composer.phar in the folder but running the command "composer install" says command not found. Please note all the commands are run in the same folder.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just use command `composer install` in command line (from same directory where composer.json is located). If you don't have an installed composer yet, first install it.

https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project root directory where composer.json is located
with opening a command prompt and using this commands :

1. make sure Your lock file contain a compatible set of packages with
   running `composer update` command
2. after that you can make sure all the packages are installed with `composer install` command
3. you can find more packages with  `composer fund` command

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to cmd or terminal
2. Make sure you are in the right path (project folder directory)
3. use `cd project_name` to go inside the folder and `cd ..` to go back up out of the folder
4. In the terminal use the command `composer install` (if you need to install composer itself, see their [official website](https://getcomposer.org/download/))
5. Your vendor folder is installed
6. In the terminal type `php artisan migrate` and run the project